# Android RecyclerView Edittext issue

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a list of editable items (received from backend). I'm using the "new" recyclerview for this. There a couple of possible viewTypes in my recyclerview:

- checkbox
- spinner
- edittext

The problem I'm having is with the EditText gaining focus. AdjustResize kicks in fine and my keyboard is shown. But the EditText that has gained focus isn't visible anymore in the list. (position in the list in the now resized portion is below the visible positions). I don't want to be using AdjustPan in this case because on top there is a pager & stuff I would like to keep fixed there..

Comment: I haven't quite grokked `LinearLayoutManager` just yet, so I'm posing this as a comment, not as an answer. Not sure this works. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/46f5ea64c398ae336c85f3aa3a3d9f36398c3576/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java), LLM picks one child view as the anchor for its scroll position. If you read the `updateAnchorFromChildren(..)` method, then setting focus on the EditText's parent view (whatever view is the actual `itemView` of your ViewHolder) should make that item the scroll anchor.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No, it still wasn't working as I wanted it to be so I ended up opening another view on top when editing something

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because, at the time the keyboard is shown, your `EditText` does not exist anymore. I have made several attempts to find a clean solution to this problem maintaining `adjustResize` input mode and good user experience. Here's what I ended up with:

To ensure that `EditText` is visible before the keyboard is shown, you will have to scroll the `RecyclerView` manually and then focus your `EditText`. 
You can do so by overriding focus and click handling in your code.

Firstly, disable focus on the `EditText` by setting `android:focusableInTouchMode` property to `false`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_review"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Then you have to set a click listener for the `EditText` where you will manually scroll the `RecyclerView` and then show the keyboard. You will have to know the position of your `ViewHolder` which contains the `EditText`:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        // you may want to play with the offset parameter
        layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.post(() -> {
            editText.requestFocus();
            UiUtils.showKeyboard(editText);
        });
    }
});
```

And finally, you must make sure that the `EditText` is made not focusable again when it naturally looses focus:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            UiUtils.hideKeyboard();
        }
    }
});
```

This is far from a simple and clean solution, but hope it will help the way it helped me.

Comment: @temirbek this is just a static utility method to hide the keyboard. You should be able to find the implementation that fits your case using a simple google search.

Answer (score 5):

Using this in layout worked :
**android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/extrasLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anchorView"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin5"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        />
```

Manifest file : Add this to the activity section **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"**

```
<activity
            android:name=".activites.CartActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cart"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
            android:parentActivityName=".activites.HomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activites.HomeActivity"/>
        </activity>
```

Comment: OP explicitly said that they don't want to use `adjustPan`

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same issue. Long story short - there is no right and elegant solution. Focus handling was always a big pain in Android.

**There multiple reasons why you are loosing focus:**

- Keyboard hides the descendant `EditText` views
- Next `EditText` is not rendered, because `RecycleView` hasn't even created a `ViewHolder` for it. Example: you have 10 views, and 5 of them are on screen and others aren't visible, because those are below.
- Some other view consumes focus, in example `CheckBox` or some `DatePicker`
- `RecyclerView` due to scroll events consumes focus
- Bunch of other hidden under-the-hood stuff

**Few words in terms of architecture and structural approach in my solution:**

- Everything works with Data binding
- RecyclerView works with Adapter that supports [AdapterDelegate](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates) approach
- Each `EditText`, `Spinner`, `DatePicker`, `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` group is a separate ViewModel which is a separate unit and handles a lot of stuff on its own.

**I've used a lot of tricks and mixed them together.** As someone already mentioned, the first step would be to add those params to your `RecyclerView`:

```
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**Base view model for all possible inputs has defined interface**, let's call it `SingleInputViewModel`, among that interface you can have defined next functions/methods:

```
void onFocusGained();

void onFocusLost();

boolean isFocusable();
```

**In each particular input item implementation you are able to control focus**, for example you are able to implement `CheckBox` as non-focusable and focus will jump to next `isFocusable() == true` item. Also you will be able to control the state and action depending on consuming/gaining focus on particular view.

**Next step for fixing some of the focus passing issues - was scrolling RecyclerView** when [IME_ACTION_NEXT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_NEXT) occurs. In such case you need to delegate your scroll logic to `LayoutManager.scrollHorizontallyBy()` or `LayoutManager.scrollToPosition()` with calculating appropriate offset or position.

**Hard and elegant approach is to override logic inside `LayoutManager`**, which is also responsible for focus handling. `LinearLayoutManager` has a lot of hidden logic, which you won't be able to override, so probably you will need to write a lot of code from scratch.

**And the last and the most complex way to fix** that is to extend `RecyclerView` and override focus search related funs/methods:

- `RecyclerView.focusSearch()`
- `RecyclerView.isPreferredNextFocus()`
- `RecyclerView.onRequestFocusInDescendants()`
- `RecyclerView.onFocusSearchFailed()`
- `RecyclerView.onInterceptFocusSearch()`
- `RecyclerView.onRequestChildFocus()`

P.S. Have a look at the `FocusFinder` and it's usage, just for general knowledge. Now you have few option to choose. I hope you will find something helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Ok
I found a solution for this problem
I'm using a library for that and it solved easily.
when you make your recyclerView by this template, it solves this problem automatically.

> NOTE: for checkbox and radiobutton only

use this

https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/RecyclerViewTemplate

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post my solution because after 2 days being blocked by this I hope that it could help someone else.

My issue was that the RecyclerView was a `wrap_content` on the height, meaning it didn't have a fixed height, and every time i clicked for the first time on one of the edit text inside it, it wasn't giving the focus on the first tap, but it was just showing the keyboard, on the second tap it was gaining the focus.

The fix was to make sure the RecyclerView has a fixed height or match_parent, i don't really know why but this worked for me!

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I put all these three things in recyclerview finally it stopped recyclerview edittext gaining focus

```
 android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because from the android 9.0 you have to write post()-> to gain focus of edittext in Previous versions you can just put
 `edittext.requestFocus();`

but from 9.0 you have to run thread to gain focus of edittext like this
 `et.post(() -> {et.requestFocus();});`

Answer (score -1):

You can scroll recyclerview to selected recycler item position on edit text focus change listener . Have a look at link to use scroll option [How to use RecyclerView.scrollToPosition() to move the position to the top of current view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328806/how-to-use-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-to-move-the-position-to-the-top-of-cu)