# How to push RecyclerView up when the soft keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adjustpan

I want to build a message layout like WhatsApp. I have an `EditText` and a `RecyclerView`.

The problem is when the keyboard appears, it hide the messages at the bottom of the list.

So let's say this the `RecyclerView`:

```
---item 1---  
---item 2---  
---item 3---  
---item 4---  
---EditText---
```

when the the keyboard appears, I get this:

```
---item 1---  
---item 2---  
---EditText---
---Keyboard---
```

but I want to get this:

```
---item 3---  
---item 4---  
---EditText---
---Keyboard---
```

NOTE: when I set `linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` it works but when there is one message it appears at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Please check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43213856/3649297) workaround.

Comment: Did you figure this out @david?

Comment: I got a solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473230/scroll-recyclerview-up-accordingly-when-keyboard-opens/58761644#58761644)

Answer (score 29):

set adjustresize for the activity with recyclerview and editText :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

add onLayoutChangeListener to your RecyclerView and set scrollToPosition to data.size() -1 in onLayoutChange:

```
  mRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
 @Override

public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,int oldRight, int oldBottom)
{

mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mMessages.size()-1);

}
    });
```

Comment: and if you use reverseLayout and setStackFromEnd = true then need use scrollToPosition(0), at what with post. Example: `recycler.post{recycler.scrollToPosition(0)}`

Comment: Thanks! Probably you should check `mMessages.size()` > 0 in order not to get an exception. See my answer below in Kotlin.

Comment: After implementing this I cannot even scroll recycler view it pushes me to the bottom (conversation view case) when I try to scroll a bit

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it, is to set setStackFromEnd() according the size of the item holder, and set adjustResize in androidManifest.

This is how I check:

```
if (recycleView.getChildCount() == items.size()){
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
}
else{
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(false);
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the condition here? What if `setStackFromEnd(true)` for all cases?

Comment: Not a good solution. Even if you insert it into `addOnLayoutChangeListener` as in the top answer, it will lift the `RecyclerView` if it is already scrolled to the end. Also, if the `RecyclerView` contains few items, it will have an empty space above, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873389/android-only-setstackfromend-only-if-recycleview-list-is-larger-than-screen.

Answer (score 2):

I am not good at English.
Use ChatRecyclerView and set the stackfromend of the linearlayoutmanager to false.

```
public class ChatRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private int oldHeight;

    public ChatRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ChatRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ChatRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        int delta = b - t - this.oldHeight;
        this.oldHeight = b - t;
        if (delta < 0) {
            this.scrollBy(0, -delta);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from [Push up content when clicking in edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292950/push-up-content-when-clicking-in-edit-text)

Just put below code in

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Just pointing to *another* SO question really isn't enough to make up an answer.

Comment: It is not enough. See the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [devdoot Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37456288/2914140) in Kotlin (I check if adapter size > 0):

```
recycler_view.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
    // Wait till recycler_view will update itself and then scroll to the end.
    recycler_view.post {
        adapter?.itemCount?.takeIf { it > 0 }?.let {
            scrollToPosition(it - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

In `AndroidManifest` add to the activity:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
```

Note that the `RecyclerView` will scroll to the last item.