# Android only setStackFromEnd only if RecycleView/List is larger than screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView that I want to start showing the bottom items, so I'm using:
`myLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)`.

It works just as I want when there are enough items to fill the screen, but if there are only a few items in the RecyclerView, it pushes them down and leaves empty space at the top of the screen

Is there any way prevent this, or to only `setStackFromEnd` if the RecyclerView is larger than the screen height?

Here's an example of what I get and what I'm trying to get:

[image: What I Get] [image: What I Want]

Comment: Which language are you using? Java or Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin, but I'll take an answer in Java, as they'll essentially be the same

Comment: What about applying `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your description, I assume that you've set the `RecyclerView` height as `match_parent`.

So, because of this, what you're seeing is just the regular behaviour. When `setStackFromEnd` is not set to `true`, your `RecyclerView` populates its views from the top (as shown in the image). However, when you set the stack from end, the opposite behaviour occurs. And, hence, you see the empty space at the top.

For removing the empty space, I'd suggest that you set your `RecyclerView` layout height to `wrap_content`. `wrap_content` was introduced for `RecyclerView` in [Android Support Library 23.2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html). Because of this, your `RecyclerView` layout would only take up the space that it needs according to the number of child views.

Also, depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could also consider `setReverseLayout(true)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there, I have set my RecyclerView to `wrap_content` with StackFromEnd set to true, but still my RecyclerView is showing empty space at the top [question with same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046894/empty-space-at-top-when-using-stackfromend-in-recyclerview)