# How do I save the state of fragments in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using a bottom navigation view which has 2 menu items. Each menu item upon clicking loads a fragment onto the `MainActivity`.
The first fragment is the home fragment where a `RecyclerView` shows a list of items and the second fragment contains a simple form.
now whenever I switch back and forth between these fragments, their previous states are lost and the fragment is recreated. This is a big issue for me because suppose I scroll to, let's say the 15th item of the list present in the home fragment. After scrolling, I navigate to the second fragment and then I navigate back. What happens is that the home fragment gets recreated and to see the 15th item I have to scroll again.
What should I do to handle this?

Comment: So you want the the first fragment to scroll back to the position you left the fragment at?

Comment: @Lucadmin Yes. I need the recycler view to scroll back to that particular item.

Comment: Just safe the view on which the user clicked and then put in the onResume method a code to scroll to this position. This could help maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328806/how-to-use-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-to-move-the-position-to-the-top-of-cu/33329765