# AdjustResize in RecyclerView not working as expected, hiding EditText below keyboard since API 30 (targetSdkVersion 30)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, window-soft-input-mode

In recyclerview, I am using item view which has an ImageView and an EditText(caption below the image).
Until I updated targetSdkVersion to 30, everything worked well. And then I changed nothing but the targetSdkVersion from '29' to '30', and now adjustResize won't work as expected.

Wierd thing is that this occurs upon the image's size.
When the Image is small and is fully shown, the RecyclerView does scroll up to show the focused EditText.
Though when the image is partially visible, the focused EditText hides behind the IME.

I have tested with below code.

MainActivity and Adapter:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myAdapter = MyAdapter()
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = myAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        }

        myAdapter.items.addAll(listOf(true, true, true))
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
    class MyViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    val items = mutableListOf<Boolean>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_edit_text, parent, false
        )
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

item_edit_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:src="@color/purple_200" />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/item_image_caption_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcd test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapplication">
    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AdjustResize not working with a partially visible image(API 30 Emulator):

[image: AdjustResize not working with a partially visible image]

If anybody knows how to solve this problem, plz help me.

Comment: I may provide an answer soon, but I'm leaving this as a comment  for now. The problem is with using EditText inside RecyclerView. I faced same problem weeks ago but only on Certain devices and my fix is change my layout. If you must RecyclerView then try the tips here - [Android RecyclerView Edittext issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050781/android-recyclerview-edittext-issue)

Comment: Not sure but have you tried using android:isScrollContainer attribute? I had keyboard clipping issue and solved using that. That might help. Give a try!